# MQTT Python-Client disconnect ungracefully

Tags: python, mqtt

I wrote basic MQTT python-client. But it disconnect ungracefully without giving  any error. When i look event log file i found it's connected and same time is disconnected ungracefully.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

Broker = "192.168.43.246"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flages, rc):
        print("Connected with result code=",rc)

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="Client123", clean_session=False, userdata=None)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
```

Here i attached a snap of event log also.

[image: event log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MikeScotty's answer is not right. What's missing is starting the MQTT network loop. The loop needs to be started to handle sending keep alive packets, doing multi leg handshakes for QoS 1/2 messages and to handle incoming subscriptions.

If you just want to stay connected or 10 seconds then something like this will work

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

Broker = "192.168.43.246"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flages, rc):
        print("Connected with result code=",rc)

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="Client123", clean_session=False, userdata=None)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start() # starts network loop on separate thread
time.sleep(10) # optionally wait some time
client.disconnect() # disconnect gracefully
client.loop_stop() # stops network loop
```

If you want to stay connected forever (or until killed) then you have 2 options

```
...
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

This will start the network loop in the foreground (and as such block until killed).

Or

```
...
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
while True:
  client.loop() # runs one iteration of the network loop
  # do something else
```

Or

```
...
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()
while True:
  # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)
    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client
```

Comment: For python that is not useable code. You probably need https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help But you also should add a prose explanation of how that code works and why it solves the problem, because of [answer].

Comment: It's also missing the starting of the network loop...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).